# What is the parameter $\lambda$ that parameterizes a spacetime trajectory $x^\mu(\lambda)$?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, variational-principle, geodesics

In Newtonian mechanics, the trajectory of a particle in three-dimensional space is parameterized as $x^i(t)$ where the parameter $t$ represents time. In relativity, one uses the proper time $\tau$ to parameterize a path in the spacetime i.e., in the form $x^\mu(\tau)$.

But sometimes, the path is spacetime is also parameterized as $x^\mu(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is a continuous parameter. For example, see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MWNs7Wfk84&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare). In this case, the proper time taken by a particle, to go from a spacetime point $A$ to point $B$ is given by $$\tau=\int\limits_{A}^B\Big(g_{\mu\nu}(x)\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{d x^\nu}{d\lambda}\Big)^{1/2}d\lambda.$$

*In the latter parameterization of the path (i.e., in the form $x^\mu(\lambda)$) what is the physical meaning of the parameter $\lambda$?*

Comment: $\lambda$ is used because the curve is not necessarily timelike and hence doesn't necessarily represent time. It just represents a parameter of the curve, which doesn't always have a nice interpretation (especially if the curve is of mixed type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda$ has no strict physical meaning in this case, because you can always just substitute some arbitrary invertible function $\lambda = f(s)$ for $\lambda$ and get $x^{\mu}(s)$ out.  But, as long as you have a non-null trajectory, you can always pick proper distance as your abitrary function (using the equation in the question), and then we might as well just assume that we're using proper distance when we start, because that does have a physical meaning (and simplifies equations, because $|{\dot x}^{\mu}{\dot x}_{\mu}| = 1$.